# Overloaded "==" operator is not called when comparing pointers

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a Task class wich has a `string text` private member. I access the variable trough `const string getText() const;`.

I want to overload the `==` operator to check if differents instances of the object have the same text.

I've declared a public `bool operator==( const Task text2 ) const;` on the class header and code it like this:

```
bool Task::operator==( const Task text2 ) const {
     return strcmp( text.c_str(), text2.getText().c_str() ) == 0;
}
```

But it was always returning false even when the strings where equal.

So I added a cout call within the `bool operator==( const Task text2 ) const;` to check if it was being called, but got nothing.

It seems that my custom `==` operator is never being called.

My header:

```
#ifndef TASK_H
#define TASK_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

    class Task {
        public:
            enum Status { COMPLETED, PENDIENT };
            Task(string text);
            ~Task();
            // SETTERS
            void setText(string text);
            void setStatus(Status status);
        // GETTERS
            const string getText() const;
            const bool getStatus() const;
            const int getID() const;
            const int getCount() const;
            // UTILS
            //serialize
            const void printFormatted() const;
            // OVERLOAD
            // = expression comparing text
            bool operator==( const Task &text2 ) const;
        private:
            void setID();
            static int count;
            int id;
            string text;
            Status status;
    };

    #endif
```

Edited the overload operation to use a reference, and got away from strcmp:

```
bool Task::operator==( const Task &text2 ) const {
    return this->text == text2.getText();
}
```

Main file:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    Task *t = new Task("Second task");
    Task *t2 = new Task("Second task");

    cout << "Total: " << t->getCount() << endl;
    t->printFormatted();
    t2->printFormatted();

    if( t == t2 ) {
        cout << "EQUAL" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "DIFF" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you are *calling* the comparison operator? Also, are you aware that `std::string` implement `operator==`? (no need to call `strcmp` on the C string?) Please add a minimal example that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
Task *t = new Task("Second task");
Task *t2 = new Task("Second task");
// ...
if( t == t2 ) {
```

You are not comparing `Task` objects, but pointers to `Task` objects. Pointer comparison is native to the language and compares *identity* of the objects (i.e. will yield `true` only if the two pointers refer to the same object or both are null).

If you want to compare the objects you need to dereference the pointers:

```
if( *t == *t2 ) {
```

Comment: Thanks! as a beginner in C/C++ I'm getting confused sometimes with pointers and references. :)

Answer (score 5):

You wrote:

> as a beginner in C/C++ I'm getting confused sometimes with pointers and references.

The solution to *that* problem is simple: **don't use pointers.** Unlike C, C++ allows you to write completely useful programs without directly using pointers.

Here is how you could have written your program:

```
int main() {
    Task t("Second task");
    Task t2("Second task");

    std::cout << "Total: " << t.getCount() << "\n";
    t.printFormatted();
    t2.printFormatted();

    if( t == t2 ) {
        std::cout << "EQUAL\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "DIFF\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1. Don't call `new`. You really didn't need it. As the currently-accepted answer points out, the use of pointers is the root cause of your problem.
2. Don't use `using namespace std;`. It introduces subtle bugs (none in your program, but it's best to avoid it.)
3. Don't use `std::endl` if you mean `'\n'`. `'\n'` means "End this line." `std::endl` means  "End this line and flush the output."

Comment: I appreciate a lot this kind of advices. Would you recommend me some book or guide of C++ coding standars or something like that?

Answer (score 3):

You are comparing pointers, not pointed-to objects.

Use `if (*t == *t2)` or you will simply check if the addresses are the same, which is obviously always false.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing pointers... Try `*t == *t2`

Answer (score 1):

No need to define as member function if the `getText` accessor is public, and there's *definitely* no need for `strcmp`, anywhere, ever.

```
bool operator==(const Task& lhs, const Task& rhs) {
    return lhs.getText() == rhs.getText();
}
```

Comment: The book I'm currently reading recommends using operator overloading methods as member functions for terms of speed

Comment: Makes no difference whatsoever. Free functions are far superior in other respects, too. You need to find a new book if it recommends the code you're writing.

Answer (score 1):

You're not comparing tasks, you're comparing pointers to tasks. `t == t2` does not mean `*t == *t2`. You cannot overload the `==` operators for built-in types.

Answer (score -1):

Try to change the method signature to:

```
bool Task::operator==(const Task &text2) const;
```

(i.e., try and use a reference for the `text2` parameter).

Comment: Was about to mention this. By the way, overloading guidelines brings up that point too: http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html

Comment: @JuanCruzViotti With this change, is your operator being called?

Comment: @JuanCruzViotti You are comparing pointers. Fix your code to compare `*t == *t2` and you will see that it will be called.

Comment: This is utterly wrong. You are allowed (and you should) actually pass by value and not by reference to allow compiler optimisation.

Comment: @bitmask: What optimization would that allow?

Comment: If you pass by reference, the compiler has no choice but to pass a pointer internally and dereference that pointer inside the function. If you pass by value the implicit copy can very likely by elided.

Comment: @bitmask: If the function takes by value, and it receives an r-value, the copy will be elided, sure.  But if it receives an l-value, then there will definitely be a copy.  However, if the function takes a reference, there will be no copy in either case.  Accepting by value is useful when you need a copy anyway, or when your objects are lightweight.  This function doesn't need any copies, and these objects do not seem very lightweight.

Comment: At any rate, you *can* (and [sometimes] should) pass by value.